# Make a cell resize and fill contents into a cell when data is on separate lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have addresses in a text file, and they're all on different lines (see 1st Image).

When I copy and paste this data to an excel file, they all appear on different lines, not matter how much I try to get it into a single cell. I have `word wrap` checked.

However, if I remove the line breaks in the text file and then do a copy and paste, all the data appears in a single cell. I have to add line breaks in the cell manually.

There are some 500+ addresses. Do you know how I can do this without having to remove line breaks and add then all over again?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you double click the cell (so that you are editing its contents rather than just selecting it) and then paste, it will paste the data in with the line breaks intact.

Comment: LOL. And I struggled with this for two days.

Comment: @norman It's cool. I remember when I first had this issue and it perplexed me for a while too!